# Спряжение глагола "пахну́ть"

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы, спряжение

*Пахну́ть* не употребляется, что ли, в настоящем времени?

Comment: так пахнет же, или нет

Comment: См. https://diffc_ru.academic.ru/5269/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: пАхнуть - обладать запахом, то есть дословно у тебя запах, пахнЕт - источает запах, чем-то пахнет. Семантика разная немного, но суть один глагол. СтрЕльнуть из пистолета - выпустить пулю из пистолета, стрельнУть из пистолета - произвести выстрел, действие то есть, а не указание на вылетающий предмет. СтрельнУлся - застрелился. Может формы глаголов в спряжения не всегда лезут, может спряжения не все формы определяют, падежей вон тоже не 6, а больше, но для простоты считают, что 6.

Comment: И ещё, Артём Луговой: обратите внимание на то, что глагол _**пахну́ть**_ - совершенного вида. Отсюда и отсутствие у него форм наст. времени.

Comment: Но смысл, если ударение на корень - то это немного другой оттенок с акцентом на существительное, а если на окончание-суффикс, то акцент на действие, признак действия. Опять же есть пАхнет и пахнЁт. ПахнУть от пахнЁт, пахнУло, то есть.

Comment: Я попозже напишу ответ, появилась мысля.

Comment: А за что меня заминусовали-то?

Comment: @Буратино: пахнёт — будущее время, а не источает. "СтрЕльнуть" нет такого, только "стрельнУть".

Comment: @Слава: при обращении лучше же без фамилии.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой будущее совершенное?

Comment: @Буратино: и что?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой пахнУть - источИть.

Comment: @Буратино: со... чего?))

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой вы не могли бы сочинить приложение со словом пахнУть? автокорректор ошибся)

Comment: Я вышел на крыльцо, и мне в лицо пахнуло нежным ароматом весны.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой нене, это пахнуло, а нужно пахнУть - такая форма заявлена.)

Comment: Какая ещё форма? Я про глагол говорил и его формы в настоящем времени, которых на самом деле и быть не может, как оказалось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Пахну́ть не употребляется, что ли, в настоящем времени?

**Да, не употребляется**.

Глагол ***пахну́ть*** (со знач. «начать дуть, повеять») — **совершенного вида** (в отличие от глагола ***па́хнуть***), а такие глаголы **форм настоящего времени не имеют**.

Comment: Что вы говорите? Прийти — приходит, подмести — подметает. Кажется, я понял! Форм настоящего времени, видимо, нету у бесприставочных глаголов совершенного вида. Их очень мало.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Нет, Артём, все глаголы совершенного вида не имеют настоящего времени. Приходит от приходить, а не от прийти, подметает от подметать и т. д.  В таблицах словоформ у таких глаголов есть прошедшее и будущее: [найти](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/найти) – нашёл, найду, а нахожу от [находить](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/находить) (несов. вид); [написать](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/написать) – написал, напишу, а пишу от писать (писал, буду писать).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Отдельного списка бесприставочных глаголов совершенного вида я не нашёл, но их не так уж и мало: *сесть, дать, взять, начать, сказать, поймать, пустить, решить, убедить, ступить, бросить, вонзить, ответить, свистнуть, прыгнуть, полоснуть, скользнуть, кольнуть, крикнуть, метнуть, стрельнуть, двинуть, блеснуть, капнуть, махнуть*.

Comment: Действительно, спасибо, Саш!